# Django: getting src attribute of iframe on views.py

Tags: python, django, iframe

Suppose I have an iframe on my template:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

There's a button, that (when clicked) will save the url of the iframe on a database. How do I access to the src attribute of the html iframe tag on my view function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access it directly in `views.py`, but you can send the URL as POST data to your view by using a hidden field.

The Django way of doing this is through the use of [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), but I'll abbreviate and use a raw HTML form. Here is the HTML that would go in your template:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="{% url app.views.your_view %}">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.w3schools.com" name="iframeurl">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit URL">
</form>
```

When the user clicks the button, a POST request will be made to your view, where you can use the URL as such:

```
url = request.POST.get("iframeurl", "")
```

If your iframe URL is going to change while the user is on the page, you can use JavaScript to keep the hidden field up to date as well.

By the way, this is a very simplified example, you'd probably also need to do some error-checking and form validation.

Comment: OK thank you. Using a hidden form was my second choice. I was just testing the water and see if there was another way. Thank you very much!